# Creating an AVD profile via ADB

Tags: android, device, android-virtual-device, adb

> **Is there any way to get or see all the device's
>   properties in Android Debug Bridege Shell?**

**adb-shell shows and retrieves only the device's, which is connected, current prosesses of the current session as I see.**

I just wonder that there is an adb-shell script command to see that device's all technical product informations.
I am planning to create an Android Virtual Device profile, but I don't have any technical information about the device. But if I can get those informations from adb, then I will be able to create that profile to build and to run android applications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To see all connected devices, you can type `adb devices`

To get the serial number, you can type `adb serialno`

Also, `adb status-window` opens a window with constant monitoring of the device

---

More crazy:

`adb shell pm list features` shows a list of features the device has

`adb shell pm list users` shows a list of users the device has (needs root)

You can't really get things like screen resolution etc through ADB unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks. "adb shell pm list features" command line helped enough for me.