# Is it possible to dump a device hardware profile to create an equivalent AVD?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

In Android Studio, when one are going to create a new Android Virtual Device, there are the option to import the Hardware Profile instead of manually fill each device parameter.

[image]

I know there are some AVD config repositories around the internet. But, does anyone know if it is possible to generate the file to be imported based on a plugged device? Maybe via adb command?

Comment: i don't know if there is something ready to use, but you could write your own tool by retrieving the informations over an adb-shell

Comment: so you want plug let's say HONOR 6, get device info and based on it create emulator, right?

Comment: @piotrek1543 I would say that is exactly what OP wants. Personally, I would benefit from it too. If there are no other solutions, I will see if I can write a tool to do it.

Comment: @Slayther many AndroidDev would be sooo thankful for that tool ;-)

Comment: They would? I might even take a bite on this one. No promises though

Comment: Related Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17951131/creating-an-avd-profile-via-adb

Answer (score 1):

You need to mount your device filesystem, then use a list of shell command to scrap all information we need from different config file.

CPU, Partitionning, RAM size, flash memory size, screen size, android version etc...

Then build your own Hardware Profile using the results of all previous commands.

Answer (score 1):

Just right click the profile that you want to export in the "Create virtual device" window, and the option to export your hardware profile as an xml shows up

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to click New AVD, then right-click a Hardware Profile, then click Clone.

Comment: I think the OP wants to create an AVD which is a "clone" of a physical device.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice In that case, you can just find out the information about your device by Googling, then enter that info into the New HardWare Profile dialog.

Comment: That certainly one solution. It requires a lot of manual work.